# Is ATM still used as a transport protocol?

Tags: cisco, transport-protocol, layer4, atm

In addition to reading new material, I enjoy reading older networking books in attempt to see where we've come from and possibly where we're going. Currently, I'm reading a book called Cisco LAN switching, which was published in 1999 as part of the CCIE Professional Development series. The book talks quite a bit about using ATM in network backbones, and it occurred to me that I rarely see anything about ATM anymore in today's network engineering.

Is ATM used anymore or has it mostly been replaced with other technologies at this point in time?

Comment: ATM is not a transport protocol, it is a physical/data-link protocol. The transport protocols are things like TCP, UDP, SCTP, DCCP, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is still used a bit, but most providers are phasing it out.

Comment: Most DSL (gshdsl, adsl flavors) is still on ATM, EFM is comparatively new. But ATM as core is getting rare, we have only very few NNIs to other operators with ATM and hopefully in 3 years time none.

Comment: PTM - Packet Transport Mode.  Common for VDSL. And used in AT&T's hacked up Uverse ADSL2+ setup. ("hack" because they're the only one's with a firmware that'll do it.)

Comment: What technologies are they phasing it out for? MPLS?

Comment: @WaxTrax whatever flavour the provider wants. MPLS is indeed one of the big candidates.

Comment: Yeah weirdly MPLS is indeed quite right answer, even though MPLS is not at same layer. Very strictly speaking Ethernet is replacing ATM, but in practice ATM like 'l2 circuits' are build on top of the ethernet with MPLS.